# Accidentally Changed Wordpress Url

Tags: urls, directory, home-url

So I have two different wordpress applications located at

test/wordpress1

test/wordpress2

I wanted to switch between them under the same domain (localhost) so while on the wordpress1 application, I set the directory to localhost:8888/test/wordpress2. Didn't plan out as I have planned. I am still in the wordpress1 application but now its pointing to the wrong folder. Now everything is messed up. Any ideas on how i set the directory of wordpress1 application back to localhost:8888/test/wordpress1? And also what is the easier way to switch between 2 wordpress sites in localhost? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a local install, it's fairly trivial to fix this. Just use phpMyAdmin to reset `home_url` and/or `site_url` in the `wp_options` table in the database.

Switching between two localhost installs is also fairly straight-forward: just don't actually use "localhost" for anything.  Instead, set up a unique domain in your system's hosts file for each install:

```
127.0.0.1    site1.localdomain
127.0.0.1    site2.localdomain
```

Then, in Apache, set each of these domains to point to your different installations (use your vhosts setup).  Make sure `site_url` and `home_url` are set properly and you're good to go.